# div id disappears after saving page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am encountering a strange problem in wordpress as the 'id' attribute gets disappeared from the '' after saving page in wordpress.

This means if I try to save '' in a page then after save it shows ''.

I don't get a clue to fix this issue.

So please help me in sorting out this problem as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saving the page with the visual editor or the html editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem and solution are described in detail here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_update_post-strips-css-id-attribute?replies=7

In short, this is due to WordPress' [KSES](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) module, which according to WordPress,

> ...makes sure that only the allowed HTML element names, attribute names and attribute values plus only sane HTML entities will occur in $string.

According to the post, one of the contributors solved this problem by *"inserting the following code just before the call to `wp_update_post`."*

```
global $allowedposttags;
$allowedposttags['div'] = array('align' => array (), 'class' => array (), 'id' => array (), 'dir' => array (), 'lang' => array(), 'style' => array (), 'xml:lang' => array() );
$allowedposttags['iframe'] = array('src' => array () );
```

For a global solution, make sure to include:

```
define('CUSTOM_TAGS', true);
```